# using event delegation to highlight cell in the table

Tags: javascript

I don't understand this js code here in this example. This code is to highlight a cell on click. Instead of assigning an onclick handler to each (can be many) – we’ll setup the “catch-all” handler on element. It will use event.target to get the clicked element and highlight it. But I don't understant the js part here. I want detailed explanation for it and if there any other method to do the same thing.

```js
        let table = document.getElementById('bagua-table');
        let selectedTd;
        table.onclick = function(event) {
          let target = event.target;

          while (target != this) {
            if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
              highlight(target);
              return;
            }
            target = target.parentNode;
          }
        }

        function highlight(node) {
          if (selectedTd) {
            selectedTd.classList.remove('highlight');
          }
          selectedTd = node;
          selectedTd.classList.add('highlight');
        }
```

```css
#bagua-table td {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  background-color:#000;
  color: #fff;
}
#bagua-table .highlight {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
     <table id="bagua-table">
          <tr> 
            <td class="nw"><strong>Northwest</strong></td>
            <td class="n"><strong>North</strong></td>
            <td class="ne"><strong>Northeast</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td class="w"><strong>West</strong></td>
            <td class="c"><strong>Center</strong></td>
            <td class="e"><strong>East</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sw"><strong>Southwest</strong></td>
            <td class="s"><strong>South</strong></td>
            <td class="se"><strong>Southeast</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the code is doing is handling the event at the `<table>`. When a user clicks any one of the cells an event is generated and bubbles up to parent elements. The initial `target` in this case is the cell that was clicked and the `if (target.tagName == 'TD')` code block is triggered. This in turn calls the `highlight` function to set the new highlighted cell by removing the `.highlight` class from last highlighted cell and add it to the currently targeted one.

In order to be more robust, the code doesn't make an assumption about what element generates the event, because the `<td>` cells can also contain other html tags. This is why it needs to have the `while (target != this)` loop. The original target might not be a `<td>` tag but one of it's ancestors will be.